# Can't install or deploy h2-console for JBoss

Tags: java, jboss

I've been working through the instructions here: http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/h2-console/#deploy_the_h2_console/

However, I can't figure out what is meant by this line of the instructions: "Deploy the console by copying the QUICKSTART_HOME/h2-console/h2console.war to the $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments directory."

After installing the greeter quickstart, I did not have an "h2console.war" anywhere. So I downloaded all of the quickstarts from here: http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/ after which I had that file.

I then copied that file to the suggested folder, but that didn't seem to do anything as the suggested localhost does not load the console.

I've searched high and low but the documentation on h2-console installation seems sketchy at best. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test it with Wildfly8.Alpha4 and work as aspected.

When you copy the h2console.war in $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments you must see:

```
12:17:11,279 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "h2console.war" (runtime-name: "h2console.war")
12:17:11,394 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018210: Register web context: /h2console
12:17:11,472 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018559: Deployed "h2console.war" (runtime-name : "h2console.war")
```

on the Application Server's server.log. After that you can use the console at `http://localhost:8080/h2console/`.

Comment: Turns out I can't aim properly with drag and drop... I had put it in the wrong folder! I'm accepting your answer – thx for taking the time to try it out.